# Equicontinuity of $ f^n (x) = \frac{1}{n} \cos(nx)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, equicontinuity

I have to prove the equicontinuity of $ f^{(n)} (x) = \frac{1}{n} \cos(nx)$ and the unequicontinuity of  $g^{(n)} (x) = \cos(nx)$ for $f^{(n)}, g^{(n)} := [0,1] -> \mathbb{R}$

I rarely heard anything about equicontinuity and don't know what to do here. Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By the mean value theorem, we have
\begin{align}
|f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(y)| \leq |x-y|.
\end{align}
where the inequality is independent of $n$.